# XCode - Stacking UI Elements in Storyboard bad practice?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a question about using the Storyboard IB. A lot of the times when I building interfaces   on the storyboard I have some UI elements stacked on top of each other. I just show and hide them selectively to give a clean interface. For example, I would put a pickerview stacked over some uitexboxes. Is this bad practice? I figured this is not a bad thing to do since I would probably be doing the same if I were building an interface programmatically, it just looks ugly sometimes using the wysiwyg builder. I just had a developer look at my storyboard and he was basically "wtf" when I had UIPickerView and UiDatePicker over some UITexboxes.

Thanks!
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the type of person you are. If you prefer things to stay clean, do it programmaticly, it you want things easier, just stack them. I only stack a few things, and I will give my reason below.

There is one drawback. If you are creating all the elements, and simply stack them, then you are relying to much on the cocoa constraints. Now, everything may appear to work properly at first, but then what if Apple came out with another device with different resolutions. Things may now appear to be messed up.

When you code the elements yourself, you are more aware of the constraints and can create formulas to adjust it based on the screen size. You are fortunate enough to be using iOS, where the amount of devices is limited. That said, if you were to suddenly start developing for Android, you might find that yourself stuck.

One other thing, if you do stack things, be sure to use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). Most likely you are, but if you are not, then creating elements on storyboard will be brought into memory immediately, instead of waiting until they are called out of "hidden". ARC can figure out that you don't really want things to be brought into memory if you start with items hidden.

Anyway, at the moment it really comes down to you. I personally find it very practical to stack some items, but I do like to see what I am doing. Good luck.

Comment: I think time has proven this answer to be "wrong", with new devices and ios 8 constraints are REALLY powerful, so I would advice to use interface builder when possible. Stacking, however, is not probably the best option, you should try to keep your storyboard simple and reuse your interface when possible (for example, you should ALWAYS consider to design reusable cells for tables and collections in dedicated XIBs).

Answer (score 2):

Everybody has their programming style. I don't think there is an absolute right way about this but sticking to the guidelines will definitely make your life easier.

Also applying universal rules makes your codes/IBs more readable.

IMO, stacking is not the best thing if you are doing an average sized app. Also keeping them all programmatically also is not the best solution. I would recommend separating UI items in different classes IBs and treat them as reusable components across the app. By doing this you can keep your memory less busy and your storyboards are going to be much lighter.